# IBM Worklight 6.2 No runtime console in WAS ND 8.5.5

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I deployed a worklight sample project "sample.war" into a clustered environment in IBM WAS ND 8.5.5 using Worklight Server Configuration tool.

ENVIRONMENT DETAILS:

Worklight build: 6.2.0.00.20140801-1709

IBM WAS ND: 8.5.5.0

**"Server error.Contact the server administrator"** while try to access the Worklight Console[http:// servername:9080/worklightconsole]

Error log from Sytemout.log

```
[10/5/14 6:31:54:373 PDT] 000000b2 RuntimeServic E   No user in security context! A <security-constraint> may be missing from web.xml.
[10/5/14 6:31:54:630 PDT] 000000af PrivExAction  W   J2CA0144W: No mappingConfigAlias found for ConnectionFactory or DataSource jdbc/WorklightAdminDS_Work
```

[server.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7nWAYIOE2qYbm9xX2MzcHdud0k/view?usp=sharing)

SystemOut.log traces

[SystemOut.log traces](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7nWAYIOE2qYTHVqVjFFMkNETEk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: *Edit the question* with the following: full worklight build number, full WAS version, your server.xml, anything else you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Updated the question with details.

Comment: Do you have an exception stack trace in the SystemOut.log ?

Comment: I have updated with systemout.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `No user in security context!` is an indication that application security is not enabled in the application server.

The remedy is:

1. Enable administrative security in the WAS console. Then enable application security in the WAS console. See also http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_securing_wladmin.html?lang=en
2. Configure the mappings of the JEE roles, as described in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_configuring_was_for_wl_admin.html?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

There's no obvious application problem in your log file.
And the runtime declared it could sucesfully synchronize line 371 of the log ' Result: worklight: worklight1/ihsCell01/wl1Node01/10.10.11.117: Runtime was synchronized successfully'

I suspect that the issue is that the console fails to communicate with the administration service.
I would try to define the endpoint property for the Console

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/c_endpoint_admin_services.html?lang=en